# MarkerWithLabel Google Maps Custom Marker

Tags: jquery, maps

I am using MarkerWithLabel with Google Maps v3 Javascript API.

I current create custom markers, and use the labelContent attribute of the MarkerWithLabel to display my icon. I do it this way so that I can dynamically rotate the icon depending on the heading. That works flawlessly.

Now, I want to add a label to the icon as well.

My Code:

```
var iconLabel = document.createElement("img");
iconLabel.src = icn+"f.png";
iconLabel.setAttribute("id","img"+$i);

var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
    position: point,
    icon: boatIcons["blank"],
    shadow: boatIcons["blank"],
    draggable: false,
    map: theMap.map,
    flat: true,
    optimized: false,
    visible: true,
    labelContent: iconLabel, 
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(16,16), 
    labelClass: "labels", 
    labelVisible: true,
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
    labelInBackground: false
});
```

This creates the IMG fine. But how do I create a DIV, add some text to it, then add the above IMG, then add it to my marker?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following snippet from my code:-

```
var marker5 = new MarkerWithLabel({position: latlngE, 
    draggable: false,
    raiseOnDrag: false, 
    labelContent: "Pnt: 5",
    labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(20, 0),
    labelClass: "labels",         // the CSS class for the label
    labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
    icon: {url: './images/arrows/Dot.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)},
    marker: MarkerWithLabel});
```

The key is in specifying the option: marker: MarkerWithLabel

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_tutorial